# Class named Purchase that store user input from textboxes vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class

Using the getters and setters solution you gave me, am getting an error "Purchase1 is used before it has been assigned a value" when l call the class so that l can add data into the instance methods  here is the code l have written

```
Private Sub btnRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click

    Dim purchase1 As Purchase

    purchase1.description = txtitem.Text
    purchase1.price = txtprice.Text
    purchase1.quantity = txtquantity.Text

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim purchase1 As Purchase

    txtitem.Text = purchase1.description()
    txtprice.Text = purchase1.price()
    txtquantity.Text = purchase1.quantity()
End Sub
```

Comment: _getting a semantic error_ Could you write exactly the error message?

Comment: 1) The data is meant to be held in the instance of the class, not in user interface controls. So the `Inherits Form1` does not belong in that class. 2) You will find that if you set [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) then Visual Studio can help with some errors like attempting to set a string to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to are trying to make an object that will act as an intermediary to the textboxes on `Form1`. If that's the case, you should pass a reference to `Form1` when creating a `Purchase` object:

```
Public Class Purchase

    Private _form As Form1

    Public Sub New(form As Form1)
        _form = form
    End Sub

    Public Property description() As String
        Get
            Return _form.txtitem.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _form.txtitem.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property quantity() As Integer
        Get
            Return Ctype(_form.txtquantity.Text, Integer)
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _form.txtquantity.Text = value.ToString
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property price() As Double
        Get
            Return CType(_form.txtprice.Text, Double)
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _form.txtprice.Text = value.ToString
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

A better approach would be to add events on your `Purchase` class and update your Form when the event is raised:

```
Public Class Purchase

    Private _description As String
    Private _quantity As Integer
    Private _price As Double

    Public Event HasBeenUpdated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Public Property description() As String
        Get
            Return _description
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If _description <> value Then
                _description = value
                RaiseEvent HasBeenUpdated(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property quantity() As Integer
        Get
            Return _quantity
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If _quantity <> value Then
                _quantity = value
                RaiseEvent HasBeenUpdated(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property price() As Double
        Get
            Return _price
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            If _price <> value Then
                _price = value
                RaiseEvent HasBeenUpdated(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

In `Form1`, you can create an instance of `Purchase` and handle its `HasBeenUpdated` event:

```
Private WithEvents _purchase As New Purchase

Private Sub _purchase_HasBeenUpdated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _purchase.HasBeenUpdated
    txtDescription.Text = _purchase.description
    txtQuantity.Text = _purchase.quantity.ToString
    txtPrice.Text = _purchase.price.ToString
End Sub
```

You will also need to update the `Purchase` object when data entry is completed, perhaps using a Save button:

```
Private Sub SavePurchaseData()
    With _purchase
        .description = txtDescription.Text
        .quantity = CType(txtQuantity.Text, Integer)
        .price = CType(txtPrice.Text, Double)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer! OP, see [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))